# doctrine select/filter on child collections

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I -roughly-  have this hierarchy :-

```
class City {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\District", mappedBy="city")
 */
private $districts;
}

class District {

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isRemoved;

}
```

and i am attempting to query Cities , but i don't want to view removed districts in the query.
my current solution involves looping over the districts and checking the removed attributes and removing the districts from the return object.

my other option was writing a detailed query from scratch using the query builder , but that -though may work in this case - becomes exponentially more complex as the hierarchy deepens.

Answer (score 1):

Seems very simple to me, maybe I didn't understood well, but let give it a try

```
$cities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->createQueryBuilder('c')
   ->select('c', 'd')
   ->leftJoin('c.districts', 'd')
   ->where('d.isRemoved = 0')
   ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

this should give you cities with associated districts collections having isRemoved to false.

hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you , but the deeper the hierarchy , getting the result in a single query becomes cumbersome. I was wondering if there were ways  to optimize this . maybe i should implement a repository method to filter children , and children of children